# Can't set color filter to overflow icon in Toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-menu, colorfilter

Why does Kotlin not allow me to apply a color filter to the overflow icon in my Toolbar?

> Expression 'colorFilter' of type 'ColorFilter' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Kotlin**

```
    mToolbar.overflowIcon?.colorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)

    // 
    val myAttr = intArrayOf(R.attr.tintColor)
    val taAttr = this.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(myAttr)
    val colorAttr = taAttr.getColor(0, Color.BLACK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Change `colorFilter()` to `setColorFilter()`.

---

There are two `setColorFilter()` methods on `Drawable`.

One takes a `ColorFilter`. That matches a corresponding `getColorFilter()` method. Kotlin treats those as being syntactically equal to a `var` named `colorFilter`. So, if you had a `ColorFilter` object, you could write:

```
 mToolbar.overflowIcon?.colorFilter = myReallyCoolColorFilterNoReallyItAddsBlueTintToEverything
```

The other `setColorFilter()` call takes the two parameters that you are specifying: the color and the `PorterDuff.Mode`. However, that method is `setColorFilter()`, not `colorFilter()`. So, either switch to `setColorFilter()` or:

```
 mToolbar.overflowIcon?.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(Color.RED, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Since you are trying to reference `colorFilter`, Kotlin assumes that you mean the `colorFilter` property, and that is not a function type and cannot be called like one.

Comment: `setColorFilter` is deprecated

Comment: @MacaronLover: I updated the answer to show using `BlendModeColorFilter`, which is what the docs for the deprecated `setColorFilter()` show as the alternative.